# How many sampradaya are there of lord ram?

Tags: rama, tradition, sects

I know few like Ramdasi, Ramanandi, Ramsnehi so want to know a full list of names & if possible some basic info of those each sampradaya

Comment: This might be of help http://lordrama.co.in/sri-vaishnav-parampara.html

Comment: Yea that site has best & all info u need about lord ram but it focuses specially on Ramanandi sampradaya so they have mentioned other sampradaya but those r not of ram but different sects in sri sampradaya so I wanted all names of sampradaya of ram but fine u tried to help.. Thank u lord ram bless u

Comment: Well I too think that these 3 are the ones, which we are aware of.